# learning geometry for artists?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

In highschool we learned geometry separate from algebra, all with the same teacher.  I would get 100% in geometry and failing grades in algebra.  I later read in the arts and now have a PHd in psychology.  I am from a family of artists and find my drawings and etchings tend towards repeated patterns and symetry.  I recently started reading King of Infinite Space by Siobhen Roberts, a biography of Donald Coxeter.  It is an excellent book and has rekindled a curiosity about geometry.  Would you recommend I read Coxeter's books or vis there another route for someone who is interested in learning more geometry but still wanting to avoid algebre?

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to math.SE!
You mentioned that you came from a family of artists, allow me asking you, if Ernest Hemingway your relative, is he?

Comment: You might find it interesting that that islamic artists created aperiodic tilings 500 years before they were rediscovered by matheticians in the 1960's. http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=islamic-artisans-constr

Answer (score 3):

Why not judge for yourself what you like or not?

Two classics :

- [Hilbert (1932) Geometry and the Imagination](http://books.google.fr/books?id=d6sBd9h1HbMC&pg=PA1)
- [Coxeter (1967) Geometry Revisited](http://books.google.fr/books?id=VdAM58ksvcIC&pg=PA1)

More recent :

- [Mumford (2006) Indra's pearls The vision of Felix Klein](http://books.google.fr/books?id=kC5kdUirHHoC&pg=PA1)
  (a very nice book with some algebra...)
- [Ebert (2003) Texturing & Modeling - A procedural approach](http://books.google.fr/books?id=bDlSJd8GfMcC&printsec=frontcover)
  (a personal choice for the Worlds we may create using a computer...)

A list at Amazon [Geometry and Beyond](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-and-Beyond/lm/R1Y7E7GSNW0QG1).

Comment: I cannot upvote enough for Hilbert's book! A real gem!